# Why is condition variable also called condition queue if it is not implemented as a queue?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

In Javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html,

> Conditions (also known as condition queues or condition variables) provide a means for one thread to suspend execution (to "wait") until notified by another thread that some state condition may now be true.

I wonder if condition variables in Java really have a queue under the hood. I doubt so because if the lock is unfair, the waiting threads won't be awakened in a First-in-first-out manner, therefore it is hard to justify why a condition variable is also named after "condition queue".

Does anyone know if the "condition queue" term makes sense? If yes, why?

Comment: A queue is only fair if the most recent arrival is forced to the end of the queue.  If it can somehow bypass the queue, then it's not fair.  But in any case, a classical condition variable (as defined by Hoare) implies some way to track waiting threads, i.e., a queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does anyone know if the "condition queue" term makes sense? If yes, why?

It makes sense.

In general, it can be hard to justify the *literal* meaning of technical terminology.  And generally not a useful thing to dig too deeply into ... unless you find such things interesting.  (For example, why do we use the term "bug"?  Programs do not contain insects!)

In this case there is no such difficulty.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)#Condition_variables_2) says this:

> Conceptually a condition variable is a queue of threads, associated with a monitor, on which a thread may wait for some condition to become true.

Indeed, in some contexts they *may be* implemented using strict FIFO queues.  It is just that strict queues are typically <sup>1</sup> not used in implementations of the Java `Condition` interface.  (And certainly, the Java `Queue` API is not used for this.)

The bottom line is that the parenthetical "also known as condition queues or condition variables" remark is there to help people who *currently* use those two terms in other contexts to relate to what this javadoc documentation is describing.

---

<sup>1 - In fact, since `Condition` is actually an interface, it is possible that *some* implementation of the interface *could* use queues.  Alternatively, since the thread scheduler implementation is actually in the OS, it is possible that strict queues *could* be used on some operating systems.</sup>

Comment: Further, as [explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63522058/2711488), the typical lock/condition implementations actually use a queue under the hood, as there is no difference between fair and unfair locks in that regard (maintaining two different implementations would be too costly). The actual difference is that unfair locks allow arriving threads to bypass the queue immediately when locking succeeds (even fair locks allow that when using `tryLock`).