# What is the purpose of fairness parameter in REENTRANT LOCK in JAVA?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I found the following text while going through Java doc of Reentrant lock:

> fairness of locks does not guarantee fairness of thread scheduling. Thus, one of many threads using a fair lock may obtain it multiple times in succession while other active threads are not progressing and not currently holding the lock.

As per my understanding it means, if the OS scheduler schedules the same thread (which was previously acquiring the lock) and it tries acquire the same lock again, Java would allow it to acquire and won't obey the fairness parameter value. Could someone please tell what could be the purpose of fairness parameter then and in what condition one should use it.
I am just thinking if its just like a priority value, which might influence the scheduler but cant guarantee the thread execution order.

Comment: Thread scheduling is different by that you can have many times more active threads than your system has cores so some are waiting to get processing time. On the other hand if multiple threads are actively trying to acquire the lock the lock's fairness parameter would influence which of them gets it. What the docs say is that you could have many threads that _might_ want the lock but if the thread scheduler only executes one of them it will get the lock even if it held it before already.

Comment: @Thomas so its just like an hint to the OS. Same as priority value.

Comment: No not really, the lock handles fairness by itself. Thead scheduling would be handlet by the JVM as well but would also get influenced by the OS, i.e. how the JVM process itself is scheduled. For the lock, consider the following: thread A gets the lock and releases it, now thread A and B would want the lock again but since B is scheduled later than A, A gets the lock again because nobody is waiting it yet (B didn't try to acquire the lock yet).

Comment: @Thomas Do you know thread B will be not considered because its in blocked state rather than runnable state when A tries to acquire the lock again ?

Comment: No, B might be active and runnable but the scheduler might just not run it or run it early enough for whatever reason. The 2 concepts are only loosely related - check Solomon's and Holger's answers, they are describing this in more detail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a naïve view, the behavior of threads using a fair lock would be like

| Thread 1 | Thread 2 | Thread 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Acquire | Do something | Do something |
| Critical Section | Try Acquire | Do something |
| Critical Section | Blocked | Try Acquire |
| Release | Acquire | Blocked |
| Do something | Critical Section | Blocked |
| Try Acquire | Release | Acquire |
| Blocked | Do something | Critical Section |
| Acquire | Do something | Release |

“Try Acquire” refers to a call to `lock()` that does not immediately succeed because another thread owns the lock. It does not refer to `tryLock()` which isn’t fair in general.

In this naïve view, the threads get the lock in the order “Thread 1”, “Thread 2”, “Thread 3”, because that’s the order of acquisition attempts. Especially when “Thread 1” tries to acquire the lock right at the time “Thread 2” releases it, it won’t overtake as would happen with an unfair lock, but rather, “Thread 3” gets it because it waits longer.

But, as the documentation says, thread scheduling is not fair. So the following may happen instead.

| Thread 1 | Thread 2 | Thread 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Acquire | Do something | Do something |
| Critical Section |  | Do something |
| Critical Section |  |  |
| Release |  |  |
| Do something |  |  |
| Acquire | Try Acquire | Try Acquire |
| Critical Section | Blocked | Blocked |
| Critical Section | Blocked | Blocked |

The empty cells represent phases in which the threads simply do not get any CPU time. There might be more threads than CPU cores, which includes the threads of other processes. The operating system may even prefer to let “Thread 1” continue on a core rather than switching to the other threads, simply because that thread does already run and switching takes time.

Generally, it’s not a good idea to try to predict the relative timing of reaching a certain point like the lock acquisition by the preceding workload. In an environment with an optimizing JIT compiler, even two threads executing exactly the same code with exactly the same input may have entirely different execution times.

So when we can’t predict the time of `lock()` attempts, it’s not very useful to insist on the lock to get acquired in that unpredictable, unknown order. One explanation why developers still want fairness, is that even when the resulting order is not predictable, it should ensure that every thread makes progress instead of infinitely waiting for a lock while other threads are repeatedly overtaking. But this brings us back to the unfair thread scheduling; even when there is no lock at all, there is no guaranty that all threads make progress.

So why does the fairness option still exist? Because sometimes, people are fine with the way it works in most cases, even when there is no strong guaranty that it will always work that way. Or simply, because developers would repeatedly ask for it if it didn’t exist. Supporting fairness doesn’t cost much and doesn’t affect the performance of the unfair locks.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for putting so much efforts to make it simple and understandable. I assume 1) Thread1 makes lock acquisition request (missing in the above table) when Thread2,3 were not running on CPU. 2) "not progressing" comment from JAVA doc refers to the time when threads are not given any CPU time rather than in "Blocked state".

Comment: Not having CPU time is the most common reason for “not progressing”. Other reasons could be “running exceptionally slow” because the JIT didn’t kick in yet or “being stopped for on stack code replacement” because the JIT *did* kick in or “waiting for the garbage collector” during an allocation attempt.

Comment: The Blocked state and waiting for CPU is actually same here because as per doc "if a thread is waiting for lock acquired by other thread, it become disabled for thread scheduling purposes". In Blocked state its not given any cpu time.

Comment: The blocked state is the result of the `lock()` attempt which the fair lock considers. Just not getting CPU time from the scheduler before the `lock()` attempt is what the lock doesn’t know about. The thread doesn’t get CPU time in either case, but the difference regarding the lock is what this is all about.

Answer (score 4):

> fairness of locks does not guarantee fairness of thread scheduling. Thus, one of many threads using a fair lock may obtain it multiple times in succession while other active threads are not progressing and not currently holding the lock.

I interpret "not progressing" to mean, "not progressing for reasons *not related to the lock in question.*" I think they're trying to tell you that "fairness" only means anything when the lock is so heavily contested that there often are one or more threads awaiting their turn to lock it.

If thread T releases a "fair" lock that no other thread currently is awaiting, then "fairness" has no impact on which thread will get it next. That's just a straight-up race between the threads, as moderated by the OS scheduler.

It's only when multiple threads are waiting that a fair lock is supposed to "favor" the one that's been waiting the longest. In particular, I would *hope* that if some thread T releases a "fair" lock that other threads are awaiting, and then thread T *immediately* tries to lock it again, that the `lock()` function would notice the other waiting threads, and send T to the back of the queue.

But, I don't actually know how it is implemented in any particular JVM.

---

P.S., IMO, "fairness" is like a bandage to stop the bleeding from a compound fracture. If your program has a lock that is so heavily contested that "fairness" would make any difference, then that's a serious design flaw.

[The same Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) also says,

> Programs using fair locks accessed by many threads may display lower overall throughput (i.e., are slower; often much slower) than those using the default setting.

Comment: Hi, So when fairness is set to true, Does it break the property of Reentrant lock?

Comment: @Turtle No, Thread can reacuire the lock if its already holding. Here the scenario is when thread tries to acquire the lock after releasing it.

Comment: "if some thread T releases a "fair" lock that other threads are awaiting,". Here other threads refering to the threads which are in running state at that time and trying to acquire the lock, Right?. Lets say For e.g. There are total 3 threads T1, T2, T3 ordered by their arrival time. At time when T releases the lock and tries to acquire it again, only T2 was in running state and others in waiting state. T2 will acquire the lock ? Please correct I am bit lost here. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Tarun, there is no `RUNNING` state in Java. Only `RUNNABLE`, which means that the JVM is unaware of any reason why the thread should not be allowed to run. (I.e., a thread that actually _is_ running is still called `RUNNABLE` by the JVM.  The state of a thread that is awaiting a monitor lock is `BLOCKED`. I don't know off the top of my head what state the JVM assigns to a thread that is awaiting a `ReentrantLock`, but if I were in charge, then that also would be `BLOCKED`.

Comment: ...[Javadoc for the `Thread.State` enum](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/loom/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.State.html) says a thread awaiting a `LockSupport.park()` call (used by `ReentrantLock`) is `WAITING`. I confirmed it by experiment. That makes me sad. <frowny-face/> If I'm debugging a Java app, I would like the thread state to clue me in to why some thread isn't running. If it's `BLOCKED` I know it's trying to get in to a `synchronized` block. I use `ReentrantLock` for all the same reasons I use `synchronized`. I'd rather it was the same (or a similarly named) state.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Thanks. If only T1 is in runnable state when T released and acquire the lock. JVM will compare the arrival time of T with T1 only rather than with T1,T2,T3 And T1 will get the lock instead of T3. is this understanding right now? Thanks a lot for your efforts.

Comment: @Tarun, a thread can't be in `RUNNABLE` state if it is awaiting a `ReentrantLock`. It will be in `WAITING` state. If some thread T releases a `ReentrantLock` while other threads are `WAITING` for the lock, then _ideally,_ the thread T1 that was `WAITING` the longest will be the next one in to the critical section. Even if T immediately tries to re-acquire the lock, T1 should _usually_ be the winner, and T should go to the back of the queue.

Comment: I say, "ideally," and "usually," because the spec doesn't guarantee that behavior. Multi-threading is tricky at the lowest levels of implementation, and its tricky in different ways on different platforms. Relaxing the requirement allows implementors more freedom to use the best tricks: An implementation that usually lets T1 run before letting T run on some platform potentially could perform \*much\* better than an implementation that is guaranteed to always let T1 run before T runs.

Comment: A practical example are the virtual threads of project Loom, which have no preemptive switching in its current implementation and perhaps won’t ever have. So a thread successfully acquiring the lock and never having a reason to give up the CPU will continue to run while the other virtual threads won’t make progress when no other native thread is available.

Answer (score 2):

The `ReentrantLock` is implemented based on `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`, which is a first-in-first-out (FIFO) wait queue.

Let's say that three threads A, B, and C try to acquire the lock successively, and A acquires the lock, then B, C will be transformed into an `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer#Node` into the queue. These two threads will be suspended.

When the A thread releases the lock, it will wake up its successor node(`AbstractQueuedSynchronizer#unparkSuccessor`), that is, thread B. Thread B will try to acquire the lock again after it is awakened.

Suppose that when the B thread is awakened, a D thread suddenly comes to try to acquire this lock. For a fair lock, the D thread sees that there are other nodes in the queue waiting to acquire the lock(`AbstractQueuedSynchronizer#hasQueuedPredecessors`), and will be directly hung up.

And for unfair lock, the D thread will immediately try to acquire this lock, which means that it can try to "jump the queue" once. If this "queue jump" is successful, then  can immediately acquire the lock(This means that node B will be suspended again: it lost in the competition with the D thread, it was cut in line). If it fails, it will be suspended and enter the queue as a Node.

Why is unfair lock perform better and when to use fair lock?

This is from  [Java-Concurrency-Practice](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601):

> One reason barging locks perform so much better than fair locks under heavy contention is that there can be a significant delay between when a suspended thread is resumed and when it actually runs. Let's say thread A holds a lock and thread B asks for that lock. Since the lock is busy, B is suspended. When A releases the lock, B is resumed so it can try again. In the meantime, though, if thread C requests the lock, there is a good chance that C can acquire the lock, use it, and release it before B even finishes waking up. In this case, everyone wins: B gets the lock no later than it otherwise would have, C gets it much earlier, and throughput is improved.
>
> Fair locks tend to work best when they are held for a relatively long
> time or when the mean time between lock requests is relatively long.
> In these cases, the condition under which barging provides a
> throughput advantage ‐ when the lock is unheld but a thread is
> currently waking up to claim it ‐ is less likely to hold.

Comment: Indeed, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63522058/2711488), the only implementation difference between fair and unfair locks is the treatment of arriving threads when the lock just have been released.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with ·```when the lock just have been released.```?From my understanding of the source code, ```unfair``` lock will try to acquire the lock once anyway,  If it happens to be released at this time, then it is possible for thread to acquire the lock. But ```fair``` lock will first call ```hasQueuedPredecessors``` to see whether other threads are currently waiting for the lock. @Holger

Comment: Yes, when the current owner releases the lock, it will unpark a thread from the queue, if one exists. The unparked thread will then try to acquire the lock. Up to this point of time, another thread (including the one which just released the lock) could overtake and (re)acquire the lock bypassing the queue if either, the lock is unfair or the thread used `tryLock()` which generally ignores the fairness policy. The more time it takes to give a previously enqueued thread new CPU time, the higher the chances of someone else overtaking and the higher the benefit.

Comment: I understand what you mean. If the lock is not released, there is actually no difference between a fair lock and an unfair lock. What I want to express is that if the lock is not released, the behavior (code level) of the two locks is still different... but the end result is actually the same. My statement did not state the point. Thank you@Holger